# x+=y+=z in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know in javascript

`x = y = z` means `x = z` and `y = z`

`x+=z` means `x=x+z`;

So if I want `x=x+z` and `y=y+z`, I tried `x+=y+=z` not working

anyone have a better idea to write short code instead `x+=z;y+=z`

**EDIT**

First thanks for everyone involved in my question.
Here I wanna explain something why I have this question in first place.

I tried to write some code like `x+='some html code'`, and I need to `y+='the same html code'`. So naturally I do not want to create another `var z='the html code` first then do `x+=z` and `y+=z`

Hope my explain make sense. Anyway, I am going to close this question now. Thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to not trying to compress everything into a single line of code but write a few symbols more and keep readability...

Comment: Holy obfuscation, Batman! Just use `x += z` and `y += z`.

Comment: You're making two assignments. Why not be explicit about it? What's the need for _short code_?

Comment: `x+=y+=z` actually does `x = x + y + z` because the right side is evaluated first. That you got this wrong is a good sign that you make it too hard for yourself.

Comment: Is it for a javascript-in-a-twitter competition? :)

Comment: @ninjagecko. Sony playstation. `:)`

Comment: let minifiers and mungers prepare your code for production environments, readability and maintainability should be much higher priority.

Comment: oh, you wanted to _concatenate_, not _add_ ?!  That actually _is_ impossible!

Comment: actually - no it isn't - `x += (y += z).substr(-z.length)`

Comment: @EricYin: It would have been good to give a description of what you were actually doing when you first asked the question.

Comment: This is a good example why you should always ask about your *actual* problem, not something that's almost but not quite it...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Assuming* **addition**, and **not concatenation**, this works:

```
x -= y - (y += z);
```

but seriously, **don't use it** !

---

For those that want to figure out *how*, the sequence of evaluation (where I use `n` to show the current intermediate result) is approximately:

```
n = y1 = y0 + z  //    n = y = (y + z)
n = y0 - y1      // -> n == -z  [uses the original value of y]
x -= n           // -> x += z
```

Comment: this is awesome @Alnitak +1 for that :)

Answer (score 10):

Just use this:

```
x+=z;y+=z
```

Honestly, anything else is just going to cause somebody else maintaining your code to stop and scratch their head for a couple of minutes.  This code isn't shockingly long either...

Comment: agreed, My mantra has been "it's better to be clear than to try to be clever."

Answer (score 6):

Well, x += y += z means:

1. x = x + y + z
2. y = y + z

So, it's impossible to do x = x + z and y = y + z with x += y += z because it would means:

```
x += (y = y + z) -> x = x + (y = y + z)
```

Take the following example:

```
function sum () {
  var x = 5, y = 7, z = 3;
  x += y += z;
  console.log (x); // it shows 15 --> x = 5 + 7 + 3
  console.log (y); // it shows 10 --> y = 7 + 3
  console.log (z); // it shows 3
}
```

So, you have to do it as follows:

```
x += z;
y += z;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `x = y = z` doesn't mean `x = z` and `y = z`. It means calculate a value of expression `y = z` and then assign x the value of that expression. This is where you wrong.

Comment: This is an important point. It's certainly the cause of the misplaced expectation for the multiple `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

you can also do.. 
    x = 1, y= 2, z=3

```
x+=(y+=z)-(y-z)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [comma](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/) operator:

```
x += (y+=z,z);
```

Comment: You should probably read the updated question. The *real* reason was to avoid the `z` variable.

Comment: @Alnitak Did you see the updated question? This means your answer is not correct at all. And every answer which uses '-' operator, is not correct. :)

Comment: I did, but the answer was correct at the time it was written.

Answer (score 2):

It is not working, because what is done in the assignment

```
x += y += z;
```

is:

```
y += z
```

is evaluated first. Besides adding `z` to `x`, this assignment also returns the new value of `y` as its return value. Then, this new value of `y` becomes the operand to the other `+=`.

```
x += y
```

Well, there is probably no shorter way to write what you want than simply

```
x += z; y += z;
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in Firefox you can use destructuring assignment to do something like what you want.

```
Array.prototype.addToEach = function(x) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
        this[i] += x; 
    return this; 
};

var x = "foo", y = "bar";

[x,y] = [x,y].addToEach("baz");

console.log(x,y); // "foobaz" "barbaz"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uPzNx/ *(demo for spidermonkey implementations)*

---

Not that it has much to do with the solution, but for those who dislike native `.prototype` extensions, you could do this instead.

```
function addToEach(s) { 
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); 
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        args[i] += s;
    return args;
};

var x = "foo", y = "bar";

[x,y] = addToEach("baz", x, y);

console.log(x,y); // "foobaz" "barbaz"
```

Comment: Modifying builtins like `Object.prototype` and `Array.prototype` are strictly forbidden. http://goo.gl/CwkNL

Comment: @Engineer: `Object.prototype`, yes, I agree (when they're enumerable). `Array.prototype`, of course not. That's an overly broad generalization. Such a restriction is relevant mainly when creating code to be widely distributed. For local project code, there's absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Comment: ...of course, this could easily be accomplished without the `.prototype` extension.

Comment: You should probably read the main page: http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/ *"Every major open-source project has **its own style guide: a set of conventions (sometimes arbitrary)** about how to write code for that project."* These are in-house guidelines that Google publishes for public use according to their licensing. Nothing is universally authoritative.

Comment: Google's javascript convention defines a good style of js programming. You can accept or avoid it.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity adding to `Array.prototype` _will_ break if other people incorrectly use `for ... in ...` on the array.

Comment: @Engineer: I agree that you can accept or avoid it. That's different from making a universal statement that they're strictly forbidden.

Comment: @Alnitak: The key word in your comment is "incorrectly". I never abandon useful practices in order to accommodate poor practices. Not saying that native prototype extensions are always the best solution, but neither would I place an absolute restriction on them.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity me neither, but when I add to `Array.prototype` I do it correctly (or at least, the ES5 version of "correct") with `Object.defineProperty`, to ensure that it's not enumerable.

Answer (score -2):

This works on jsfiddle, so it must be something else you are doing...

```
x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
x += y += z;
alert(x);
```

Comment: But that's not what he's after, since `x` should equal 4, not 6.